# Mach-O header error when adding realm to watchkit project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, realm

when I add realm to the watch kit extension (original app has it already integrated) and build it I get an error:

```
error: warning: Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 1918975009
```

realm.framework and libc++ are added to the extension.

What might cause the issue?

Thanks
Sascha

Comment: I wonder how do you integrate Realm? Do you use the static or the dynamic framework? If you integrate manually with the static framework, then this is likely related to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559948/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-1918975009-in-xcode-6).

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue on my own. Instead of adding the Realm Framework only to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** I added it to Embedded Binaries, too.

Adding them to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** only solved the problem.