# Crashlytics with iOS 9 Unable to Download App

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am getting the following error:

> Unable to Download: APP_NAME could not be installed at this time [Done/Retry options]

I am on iOS 9 Beta v5. Will I not be able to install any versions of my app from Crashlytics because I am using iOS 9?

Comment: iOS 9 bydefault enables bitcode and crashlytics is not built with bitcode.
So disable bitcode from your project setting. [How to disable bitcode?](http://idiotswithios.blogspot.in/2015/09/bitcode-errorwarning-in-ios-9-xcode-7.html)

Comment: For me it was the "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" error which I found in the device logs while trying to install my app.

Comment: How do you see the device logs?

Answer (score 14):

We started to have this problem after renewing our apple developer membership. I fixed by deleting the iOS Provisioning Profiles through the apple website and generated new ones. I've also resetted my XCode cached data:

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

I've also removed all cached provisioning profiles at `/Users/<user>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Then I opened `XCode > View details > Download all` to download the new profiles and distributed a new build. It worked from then onwards.

Answer (score 10):

Found this answer on Crashlytics' forum: https://twittercommunity.com/t/download-problem-detected/52772

Basically you need to delete existing app from App Store before trying to install the beta build

Comment: I am having this issue even with a non-App-Store build being present on the device. Strange things is, this only occurs on some devices, so it seems to be a configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS9, display image URL is required in manifest.plist. It give this error because image is missing from URL.
I added a image and it is working for me, but I have my personal server. Maybe diawi.com, hockeysdk, crashlytics should update their server.

Comment: How I do that? what it the key for display image URL?? Could you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: when export a build you have a option to export manifest.plist. All fields from there are require and files should be on server. That manifest.plist should be on your server. Now diawi.com have fixed that and you can use it to install your build without export manifest.plist. Just drag and drop .ipa in www.diawi.com

Answer (score 0):

We distribute our app builds with Crashlytics Beta and hit the same problem today. Disabling the 'ios 8 download fix' checkbox fixed our problem.

In the device error log I saw
"Failed to install application"... "Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=143"
when I tried to install our build from the Crashlytics app.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-8-download-fix/34326 states that the ios 8 download fix is

> using a different bundle identifier in the download manifest to trick
>   the OS into downloading the payload

Answer (score 0):

The follow answers said that "display image URL is required in manifest.plist.",but right now my app is working without this under iOS 9.I have mistaken the bundle identifier.iOS 9 will check the value.

> iOS 9 became more strict with the manifest information:the tag,the
>   value,or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem. I  deleted and created again  " provisioning profile" , but that problem was not resolved.

I tried test option insert app store, but it failed and showed following problem "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x7263c21" .

Following this link "[Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 1918975009 in xCode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559948/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-1918975009-in-xcode-6) "  I received the answer to my question. I have double framework, I deleted it and the issue was resolved.