# Fastline + Crashlytics Unable to Download App

Tags: ios10, crashlytics, fastlane, xcode8

I have an issue with my App. I have been able to archive it with fastline and to distribute it with Crashlytics.
But then when I install the app I have a pop up with the error : "Unable to Download App" with the option to retry.

I have looked to the device logs, but I don't understand the error :

```
Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus installd(MobileSystemServices)[854] <Notice>: 0x16dff7000
-[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.sherpa-solutions.HIMSS2017; Version=713, ShortVersion=3.5> Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus installd(MobileInstallation)[854] <Notice>: <private>:Install (New):0:Success:Begin Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus installd(MobileSystemServices)[854] <Notice>: 0x16dff7000 


-[MIFileManager realPathForURL:ifChildOfURL:]: Rejecting /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.jQyktL/extracted/Payload/HIMSS2017.app/ActivTouchResources.bundle

-> /Users/jgahide/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HIMSS2017-dehtvbvvxajesreqckfuqhvjxfyj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/HIMSS2017/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ActivTouchResources.bundle, as absolute symlinks are not allowed


Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus SpringBoard[4589] <Info>: Updated: <private> Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus installd(MobileSystemServices)[854] <Notice>: 0x16dff7000
__87-[MIFileManager standardizeOwnershipAtURL:toUID:GID:validateSymlinks:removeACLs:error:]_block_invoke: 423:  invalid symlink at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.jQyktL/extracted/Payload/HIMSS2017.app/ActivTouchResources.bundle

Jun  7 16:22:50 sherpas-iPhone-6-plus installd(MobileSystemServices)[854] <Notice>: 0x16dff7000
-[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Preflight stage failed
```

I tried [Crashlytics with iOS 9 Unable to Download App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924913/crashlytics-with-ios-9-unable-to-download-app) but it didn't work.

Comment: are you able to install and run the `ipa` from the mac computer that fastlane ran on?

Comment: I tried to install the generated `.ipa` with iTunes and I got the error : "iTunes Sync : 1 item could not be synced." I tried to look at the console log on the mac, but got no luck.

Comment: How are you building the `.ipa`? I would guess that it is using an Enterprise provisioning profile (I don't use Crashlytics), and if so, it _should_ be possible to install onto the device.