# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 on submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there are a lot of possible solutions but none of them have worked for me so far. I am using a framework called Alamofire.framework and Kingfisher.framework. I built an iOS App which I would like to submit to AppStore. I archived it and then I come in the Archives window and click "Upload to App Store".

> The following error occurs: "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code:
>   0x72613c21" with the following logs:
>
> IDEDistribution.critical.log
>
> 2016-01-08 06:00:47 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items
>   with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=} 2016-01-08 06:00:47
>   +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
>
> IDEDistribution.standard.log
>
> 2016-01-08 06:00:47 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for
>   archive: UCDA, task: Validate 2016-01-08 06:00:47 +0000 [MT]
>   Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method
>   
>   2016-01-08 06:00:47 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user
>   entitlements for
>   :
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at
>   "/Users/chikitin/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/UCDA
>   1-7-16, 11.59
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/UCDA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at
>   "/Users/chikitin/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/UCDA
>   1-7-16, 11.59
>   PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/UCDA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
>   2016-01-08 06:05:27 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
>
> IDEDistribution.verbose.log
>
> 2016-01-08 06:00:47 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init

I hope someone could help me with this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 1918975009 in xCode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559948/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-1918975009-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error with a FacebookSDK framework. I removed it from the Embed frameworks list and it solved the issue. Inspect the log and find the framework causing the error.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with facebook SDK ... I create a bug task on facebook (bug report), the problem appears with the new SDK version . 
And No solution works ... 
If you have found a solution let us know. Thank you. 
I run my app without facebook connect actually.

Comment: Found a solution... It's not mandatory to add embedded framework, I just delete FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLogin From Embedded Framework and add them to "Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: Actually there is a new update on the Facebook SDK, so you add it to your project and fix the problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stan, you saved the day, i faced exactly the same issue.

Comment: @StanSarr you made my day. thaaaaaaaanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove any Frameworks’ related files in the "Copy Bundle Resources” in the build phases. Please see https://kobkrit.com/how-to-fix-found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-on-submitting-to-app-store-7d5b8ec180c

Answer (score 0):

Remove any frameworks or folders with frameworks from **Build Phases ->** **Copy Bundle Resources**:

[image]

This solved the error for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had no frameworks folder but had ios folder in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, I removed ios folder and rebuild the project, created archive again, it worked for me.