# iOS on archiving Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 1918975009

Tags: ios, google-maps, xcode6.3

I am getting the "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 1918975009" warning while archiving the project. I am using GoogleMaps framework and copying the GoogleMaps.Bundle to Copy Bundle Resources.

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559948/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-1918975009-in-xcode-6.) 
 I tried to remove the binary from Copy bundle resources but the application will get crash prompting exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''
Please help if I am mistaking anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you use Cocoapods ? It takes care all library & path issues.

Comment: Worked while using CocoaPods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, managing libraries via Cocoapods can resolve the issue. It manages the include path, linker flags and the bundled files automatically.