# An error occurred during upload. Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, swift4

So basically when I tried to upload my app it gave me this error:

[Upload Fail Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVwyG.png)

So I don't know what to do now. Because my app is a bit older, the deployment target is set to 8.0 does this make a difference? I tried so much and searched for so long. Please someone help me.

Comment: possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559948/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-1918975009-in-xcode-6]

Answer (score 0):

Somehow there is an embedded binary added to your target that shouldn't be there remove the binary and re install the pods check this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265996/5123516